# How to move equation numbers to right hand side?

Tags: equations

I'm writing a mathematical article and I want the equation numbers to appear on the right hand side and the end of the line however they are currently appearing underneath the equation on the left. How can I change this?

EXAMPLE:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{natbib} 
\usepackage[section]{placeins} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{wrapfig} 
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{ a4paper, total={170mm,257mm}, left=20mm, top=20mm, }

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Equations}
The horizontal and vertical links and network nodes can now be defined as the following matrices: \

\textbf{Horizonal Links} \newline

For 1 \leq i \leq m+1 \ $and$ \ 1 \leq j \leq n

\begin{description} 
\item[(a)]

\begin{equation} A_{ij}^X= \begin{cases} 1, & \text{if the link between ($i,j$) and ($i,j+1$) exists}\ \ 0, & \text{otherwise}\ \ \end{cases}

\end{equation} $$

\item[(b)]

\begin{equation} X_{ij} = l_{ij}

\end{equation}

where $l_{ij}$ is the length of the link between ($i,j$) and ($i,j+1$). If >there is no link between ($i,j$) and ($i,j+1$) then $l_{ij}$=0

\end{description}

\bibliographystyle{plain} 
\bibliography{references} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Right hand side is the default, so you have `leqno` or some different setup apparently?

Comment: Which document class do you use?

Comment: I'm using article at the moment

Comment: Do you use at one-column or a two-column layout?

Comment: A one-column layout

Comment: @zarko - In the process of cleaning up the OP's code (a laudable effort!), you actually removed the errors that were causing the equation numbers to show up on the left hand side of the text block and below the equations. Can you undo the changes?

Comment: @Mico, I recover old code ... in formatting I erase `$$` after equations. Is it cause error by which is OP faced? I'm sorry for any  inconvience.

Answer (score 2):

Your coding style is, shall we way, not exactly tidy. Here's a minimalist fix-up that should get you going, at least for a little while. Good news: after the code clean-up, the equation numbers show up on the right-hand edge.

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{natbib} 
\usepackage[section]{placeins} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{wrapfig} 
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{mathtools} 
%%\usepackage{amsmath}  is loaded by 'mathtools' -- no need to load it explicitly
\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{ a4paper, total={170mm,257mm}, left=20mm, top=20mm}

\begin{document}

\section{Equations}

The horizontal and vertical links and network nodes can now be defined as the following matrices

\subsection*{Horizonal Links} 

For $1 \leq i \leq m+1$ and $1 \leq j \leq n$

\begin{description} 
\item[(a)]
\begin{equation} 
A_{ij}^X= 
\begin{cases} 
  1, & \text{if the link between ($i,j$) and ($i,j+1$) exists}\\ 
  0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\item[(b)]
\begin{equation} 
    X_{ij} = l_{ij}
\end{equation}
where $l_{ij}$ is the length of the link between ($i,j$) and ($i,j+1$). 
If there is no link between ($i,j$) and ($i,j+1$) then $l_{ij}$=0

\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks yeah that's changed it :) yeah I have just been googling as I go along...